# cannot find xdebug helper icon from chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xdebug

I'm using phpstorm and xdebug
I installed xdebug helper extension.

I have used it before fine..

today, I cannot see the icon which enable the debug connection between browser and phpstorm

before [ normal ] 
==>

[image]

now 
==>

[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

choose setting / extensions / xdebug helper 
 = > options

add your testing domain [ localhost ] in Domain filter